# Refactor to remove a trailing <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Admittedly not a js expert. - How can I remove the trailing `<br>` on the last element?  Feel free to comment on the general approach and make comments or suggestions.  Thanks!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("{% url "relationship_sidebar_ajax" app_label=app_label model=model object_id=object.id %}", function(data) {
        var str = ""
        for (var item in data) {
            var itemData = data[item];
            str += '<dt>' + item + '</dt>';
            for (idata in itemData) {
                str += '<dd>' + itemData[idata].href;
                if (itemData[idata].is_owned) {
                    str += '&emsp;<i class="icon-lock"></i>';
                }
                str += '&emsp;' + data[item][idata].add_href + '</dd>';
            }
            str += '<br />'
        }
        $('#relations').append(str)
    });
})
```

Comment: you could put it at the beginning of the loop, but then youll have a leading <br> will that suffice? If not then you need to keep track of the first iteration and not add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array to hold the lines, and then join them with `<br/>` at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("{% url "relationship_sidebar_ajax" app_label=app_label model=model object_id=object.id %}", function(data) {
        var arr = []
        for (var item in data) {
            var itemData = data[item];
            var str = '<dt>' + item + '</dt>';
            for (idata in itemData) {
                str += '<dd>' + itemData[idata].href;
                if (itemData[idata].is_owned) {
                    str += '&emsp;<i class="icon-lock"></i>';
                }
                str += '&emsp;' + data[item][idata].add_href + '</dd>';
            }
            arr.push(str);
        }
        $('#relations').append(arr.join('<br />'));
    });
})
```

Comment: You know...  Sometimes the answer is so obvious you really feel foolish - nice job!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the last five characters of your string will always be `<br />` so you could always just append `str.substring(0, str.length - 5)`. It might be preferrable to wrap the `dt` and subsequent `dd` elements in a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the br tag in the beigining of string this would be helpful.

```
var str = "<br />Some string";

var regex = /^(<br\/>|<br \/>)/;

alert(str.replace(regex,""));
```